# Logic for a simple hangman game to show encoded word

Tags: javascript

I'm building a hangman game with a database. What my goal is is to store all the guessed letters in my field like "aesdfr". A single string, nothing crazy.

Then I split the letters into an array of guessed letters.

With that in mind, if I have the following

```
var word = "frog";
var stored_guesses = "frsd"; // hard coded for now
var guessed_letters = stored_guesses.split("");
```

How do I then go through the guessed letters and present back on the screen "_ " for each letter they didn't guess and show the correct letters for those they did?

I was thinking of looping over each letter in stored_guesses and replacing the original word with hypens for each letter that doesn't exist. But I'm confused.

I'm sure I'm even doing this the word way possible. Is there a better way to store guessed letters and show the encoded word?

Comment: Loop through each letter in the `word` instead and check if it's in the `stored_guesses'.

Answer (score 3):

You don't even need to bother with arrays, you can do this with a simple string replace (with a global regexp containing the negated character class of your guessed letters):

```
var word = "Long word incoming";
var guessed = " aongc";

var regexp = new RegExp('[^' + guessed + ']','g');
var display = word.replace(regexp, '_');

console.log(display);
```

DEMO: http://jsbin.com/UxixOdA/1/edit

PS: If you want to allow special symbols (other than letters) in your guessed string, you might need to escape them when creating the regexp, or you will have surprises:

```
// Guesses: a, -, z
var guessed = " a-z"
var regexp = /[^ a-z]/g // matches anything except lowercase letters
```

Comment: For the one-liner fans: `word.replace(new RegExp('[^' + guessed + ']','g'), '_');`

Comment: Thank you for such elegant code, Tibos! I tried that and it does EXACTLY what I was trying to do.. and in far fewer lines of code than any solution I would have come up with.

Can you explain
var regexp = new RegExp('[^' + guessed + ']','g');

Or link me to a page that explains what this is doing?

Comment: It creates a regular expression that matches any character except those in the guessed string. [^...] is a negated character set. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Answer (score 2):

ES5 one-liner:

```
word.split("").map( function(l) { return stored_guesses.indexOf(l) !== -1 ? l : "_" } ) .join("")
```

If you need older browser support, it can be done with a standard for loop:

```
var w = word.split("");
var display = "";
for (var i = 0; i< w.length; i++) {
    display += stored_guesses.indexOf(w[i]) !== -1 ? w[i]  : "_";
}
console.log(display);
```